# How can C# access JavaScript variables in Unity 5?

Tags: c#, unity

I have a static public boolean in a JavaScript and I want to access it in a C# script. When I tried the way that you would call a static variable from another script though, it said that the variable and script weren't recognized. Here is my JavaScript code:

```
public static var ItemPurchased = false;
function OnGUI () {
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 90, 190, 24), "Click here to collect water.")){
         ItemPurchased = true;
}
```

I do believe that the JavaScript is correct. On the other hand, here is my C# script:

```
public static bool itemowned = false;
void Update () {
    if(PurchaseItemScript.ItemPurchased == true){
        itemowned = true;
        PurchaseItemScript.ItemPurchased = false;
    }
}
```

PLZ HELP!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your *class* is not static. You need to initialize it before using:

```
public static bool itemowned = false;

private readonly PurchaseItemScript = new PurchaseItemScript();

void Update () {
    if(PurchaseItemScript.ItemPurchased == true){
        itemowned = true;
        PurchaseItemScript.ItemPurchased = false;
    }
}
```

or, make the PurchaseItemScript class static.